# How do you set the File Layout to put [ClassInitialize] and [ClassCleanup] at the top of the file using Resharper 9?

Tags: resharper, mstest, resharper-9.0

How do you set the File Layout to put the MsTest `[ClassInitialize]` and `[ClassCleanup]` methods at the top of the file using Resharper 9?

With the default set-up for R#, the methods are just alpha sorted with the other test methods

*I appreciate that I can amend the "All other members" from sort by Name, to sort first by Static and then by Name, but this seems like a quick hack*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the file layout rules that ReSharper uses for reordering file content by code cleanup, by going to ReSharper → Options → Code Editing → C# → File Layout.

Full details are available in [the web help](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/File_and_Type_Layout.html), but the idea is to create a pattern very similar to the default "NUnit Test Fixtures" pattern, but for MSTest. In fact, this is a nice idea for a default pattern, so I've added a feature suggestion you can track or vote: [RSRP-446275](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-446275)

Essentially, you want to do what the default NUnit Test Fixtures rule does.Create a new "type pattern" and add it between "NUnit Test Fixtures" and "Default Pattern". Double click to edit the pattern, and switch to constraints view by clicking the cog in the top right. Here you can say it has to be of Kind "Class" And "Has attribute" `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute`.

Switch back to Composition (rules) view, and add an "Entry" from the Toolbox. Give it a name, such as "Setup/Teardown Methods", and double click on it. This should be set up the same as NUnit's - And (Kind=Method, Or (Has attribute=Microsoft...ClassInitializeAttribute, Has attribute=Microsoft...ClassCleanup)).

The NUnit pattern defines another couple of entries - an empty one for "All other members" and one for "Test methods", which is kind=method and has attribute=Test. Something similar could be done for mutest's `TestMethod` attribute.

Comment: Excellent, that worked a treat, once I understood the significance of the cog in the designer